# How to use trained model with meka in java?

Tags: classification, weka, multilabel-classification

In WEKA, I can train a model and save it and use it in my java code for predict new data . Can I do this with meka too?
I found this example, [this link](https://github.com/Waikato/meka/blob/master/src/main/java/mekaexamples/classifiers/TrainTestSet.java) , model should train in every run of program.
how can i train only once , save that model then load it in java and use that model for new data ?

Comment: You can use..just check if classifier is already built or not and then take decision accordingly...

Comment: [this](https://github.com/bnjmn/weka/blob/master/weka/src/main/java/weka/classifiers/bayes/NaiveBayesMultinomialUpdateable.java) may help you

Comment: @ELITE building a classifier needs a train dataset like  `classifier.buildClassifier(train);`  (rest of code is in [here](https://github.com/Waikato/meka/blob/master/src/main/java/mekaexamples/classifiers/TrainTestSet.java)) , i already have a trained model .